# How can i access apache web pages from outside VMWare ESXi virtual Machine

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, vmware-esxi

I am using ESXi 4.1 and have a CentOs 6.2 Virtual Machine with apache server running. I cannot access this web server from outside the Virtual Machine.

My ESXi 4.1 is on 10.0.11.11
The VM i have setup has the IP 10.0.1.152
i can ssh to this VM from outside, but cannot access the web page

Comment: Do you have any firewall rules on the CentOS machine?

Comment: i remove firewall, but still the same problem

Comment: Then I'd ensure that Apache is configured to listen on the correct IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take ESXi out of the equation and the answer will be the same. Likely there is some firewall or apache configuration on the guest that is causing this. ESXi has nothing to do with it, since the networking is bridged.

Comment: nops i actually found the issue and confirming it, It has to do with the default Network Adapter TYPE, until CentOs 5.8 it was E1000, but for some odd reason the default is for CentOs 6.0 and up , "Flexible"

Comment: So you didn't have a driver installed for it. The same problem would occur if you were using a NIC without a native driver included by the distro.

Comment: ok i just installed centos5.8 with http option selected during install , and after disabling selinux i WAS able to access it from outside, makes me think this is /etc/httpd/httpd.conf ALL ALL ... type of issue

Answer (score 2):

You just need to open port 80 for apache:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-service=http --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```